# What [is/are] needed [is/are] additional resources. which one is correct?

Tags: singular-vs-plural

In the book 'Advanced Grammar in Use 3rd Edition' it says that 'if we use a what-clause as subject, we use a singular verb if the following main noun is singular, and either a singular or a plural verb if the following main noun is plural (although a plural verb is preferred in more formal contexts)'

- What is needed are additional resources. (or more colloquially … needed is …)

so according to this book, I can use 'What is needed ***are*** additional resources' or 'What is needed ***is*** additional resources'.

but, what should I use after What..[is/are]? because the subject of this sentence is plural. 
"What(= things that) is needed are additional resources." how come we use a singular verb in a What-clause?

Comment: No, according to this instruction, the what-clause already is set and serves as the sentence subject. You have confused the "main noun" for the subject. Do not touch the what-clause.

Comment: @YosefBaskin can we not use what as a plural relative pronoun?

Comment: Yes you can do that.

Comment: @YosefBaskin “What are needed are additional resources”, “What is needed are additional resources” which is correct ?

Comment: Sure, you can say “What are needed are additional resources.” “What is needed are additional resources” may not be incorrect, but sounds awful, so I'd reword it. Correct does not always define good wording.